# Issue connecting to EC2 windows instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm exploring the EC2 service of AWS.

I'm currently creating a ec2 windows instance. I have launched it in a custom created VPC having a public subnet.

Security group is created and associated with VPC with rules of allow all inbound traffic`[0.0.0.0/0]`(for testing purpose only).

However after getting the admin password (received after decrypting the keypair) , I'm not able to connect to windows instance using remote desktop connection.

Its displaying error message as below.

[image]

I'm not able to get where the things are going wrong.

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure EC2 instance started and you are using public IP while RDP?

Comment: Yes it's running and have a public IP.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to a security group and select RDP and open it for 0.0.0.0/0(or limited). it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the connectivity issue is as below:

The route table associated with the subnet(in which instance is launched) is not configured for the target of `internet-gateway`. So I have used the private subnet logically instead of public subnet.

Since I didn't use the VPC wizard(which will auto-configure the needed routes) to create/configure VPC and subnets, I have missed it.
Thank you all for your time and suggestions.